# Apply Newton's Method to approximate the $x$-coordinates of all intersections: $y=1=e^xsin(x);0<x<\pi$

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

> Apply Newton's Method to approximate the $x$-coordinates of all intersections: $$y=1=e^x\sin(x)\qquad 0<x<\pi$$

Let $f(x)=e^x\sin(x)-1$ and $$x_{n+1}=x_n +\frac{1-e^x\sin x_n}{e^x(\cos x_n+\sin x_n)}$$ Now I am to propose an initial approximation $x_0$ so that I am able to guarantee convergence, and this is where I am stumped.

How can I guess $x_0$ without knowing their graph? Because sometimes it is very difficult to sketch the graph and approximate $x_0$. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Newton’s method is usually well behaved when not near a root of $f’$. This one has a root at $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$. I’d recommend trying various starting points to the left and to the right of that zero of $f’$.